# How to create internal links with JS-XLSX

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx, js-xlsx

I'm trying to generate an XLSX Excel document with JS-XLSX and I can't find a way to create the equivalent of an internal link.

I have this summary page in which I'd like to present clickable links pointing to other sheets.

[image]

I've tried many combination of `cell = {l: {Target: "..", Rel: {Target: "...", Type:"Internal"}}}` but it doesn't work.  It always ends up as an external hyperlink in the generated document.

I would accept an XLSX-specific solution.

I'm using JS-XLSX 0.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to make the hyper link.

```
cell.l = { Target:"#'" + cell.v + "'!A1", Tooltip:cell.v }
```

This will anyway add the link, however, this will not format the cell as the hyper link cell. You need to format it separately. But if you hover your mouse you can find the link. By clicking on that cell, it will take you to appropriate sheet.

Comment: It's not working for me in Excel 2007.  I absolutely need to put something in front of the `#`.

Comment: You no need to put anything in front of #. But you need to note one thing that this will not format your cell to the blue color. Have you hovered your mouse cursor over those cells and clicked?

Comment: Excel 2007 refuses to open the resulting XLSX file if I don't specify the  filename part of the link.  In other words, `foobar.xlsx#'Section 1'!A1` works but not `#'Section 1'!A1`.

Comment: mmm, I am not sure about 2007. I am using 2013, where it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, internal links are not yet supported (as of 0.10.5):

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/685